# how to export cloudwatch logs to s3 by using python by using GLUE JOB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I run a code in glue job script, after its running some logs are created cloudwatch, those logs I need to store s3 bucket by using python code from gluejob. is it possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Exporting [CloudWatch] log data to Amazon S3: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html